# Pyspark DataFrame UDF on Text Column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do some NLP text clean up of some Unicode columns in a PySpark DataFrame. I've tried in Spark 1.3, 1.5 and 1.6 and can't seem to get things to work for the life of me. I've also tried using Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.

I've created an extremely simple udf as seen below that should just return a string back for each record in a new column. Other functions will manipulate the text and then return the changed text back in a new column.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def dummy_function(data_str):
    cleaned_str = 'dummyData' 
    return cleaned_str

dummy_function_udf = udf(dummy_function, StringType())
```

Some sample data can be unzipped from [here.](https://github.com/dreyco676/nlp_spark/blob/master/data/classified_tweets.zip)

Here is the code I use to import the data and then apply the udf on.

```
# Load a text file and convert each line to a Row.
lines = sc.textFile("classified_tweets.txt")
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split("\t"))
training = parts.map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1]))

# Create dataframe
training_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(training, ["tweet", "classification"])

training_df.show(5)
+--------------------+--------------+
|               tweet|classification|
+--------------------+--------------+
|rt @jiffyclub: wi...|        python|
|rt @arnicas: ipyt...|        python|
|rt @treycausey: i...|        python|
|what's my best op...|        python|
|rt @raymondh: #py...|        python|
+--------------------+--------------+

# Apply UDF function
df = training_df.withColumn("dummy", dummy_function_udf(training_df['tweet']))
df.show(5)
```

When I run the df.show(5) I get the following error. I understand that the problem most likely doesn't stem from the show() but the trace doesn't give me much help.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-19-0b21c233c724> in <module>()
      1 df = training_df.withColumn("dummy", dummy_function_udf(training_df['tweet']))
----> 2 df.show(5)
/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate)
    255         +---+-----+
    256         """
--> 257         print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
    258 
    259     def __repr__(self):
/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:
/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()
/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o474.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-12-4bc30395aac5>", line 4, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:913)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:968)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1741)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1538)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1495)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/Users/dreyco676/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-12-4bc30395aac5>", line 4, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:913)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:968)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1741)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
```

Actual function I'm trying:

```
def tag_and_remove(data_str):
    cleaned_str = ' '
    # noun tags
    nn_tags = ['NN', 'NNP', 'NNP', 'NNPS', 'NNS']
    # adjectives
    jj_tags = ['JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS']
    # verbs
    vb_tags = ['VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ']
    nltk_tags = nn_tags + jj_tags + vb_tags

    # break string into 'words'
    text = data_str.split()

    # tag the text and keep only those with the right tags
    tagged_text = pos_tag(text)
    for tagged_word in tagged_text:
        if tagged_word[1] in nltk_tags:
            cleaned_str += tagged_word[0] + ' '

    return cleaned_str


tag_and_remove_udf = udf(tag_and_remove, StringType())
```

Comment: Are you sure `l.split('\t')` returns more than one item? The index error is likely from `training = parts.map(...)`. What does your data look like - are you sure there are tabs used everywhere?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that the data has two columns. I scrubbed the data of all whitespace besides spaces before putting in the flatfile. I'll put a small sample up top.

Comment: You aren't splitting on whitespace - only tabs - `l.split()` would split on any whitespace.

Comment: Are you able to successfully load the dataframe? Can you run `training_df.show()` to confirm that it's not a problem with the original data?

Comment: @AChampion I'm aware of that. The fields are indeed seperated by tabs. I mentioned that all other white space was scrubbed so that there are no issues with extra tabs or returns breaking my table.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst yes I added a sample above.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I loaded up the data further and I might have some more bad data in there. I'm guessing that will clear it up.

Comment: There are 985 lines in your data set that only have 1 field. (149195 that have 2 fields)

Comment: Thanks I would have thought that the training_df.show(5) would have caused the rest of the parsing to happen and the show 5 records. It looks like if you don't have any transformations that does not occur. Thanks for checking my stupidity!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your dataset isn't clean. 985 lines `split('\t')` to only one value:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> lines = sc.textFile("classified_tweets.txt")
>>> parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split("\t"))
>>> parts.map(lambda l: (len(l), 1)).reduceByKey(add).collect()
[(2, 149195), (1, 985)]
>>> parts.filter(lambda l: len(l) == 1).take(5)
[['"show me the money!”  at what point do you start trying to monetize your #startup? tweet us with #startuplife.'],
 ['a good pitch can mean money in the bank for your #startup. see how body language plays a key role:  (via: ajalumnify)'],
 ['100+ apps in five years? @2359media did it using microsoft #azure:  #azureapps'],
 ['does buying better coffee make you a better leader? little things can make a big difference:  (via: @jmbrandonbb)'],
 ['.@msftventures graduates pitched\xa0#homeautomation #startups to #vcs! check out how they celebrated: ']]
```

So changing your code to:

```
>>> training = parts.filter(lambda l: len(l) == 2).map(lambda p: (p[0], p[1].strip()))
>>> training_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(training, ["tweet", "classification"])
>>> df = training_df.withColumn("dummy", dummy_function_udf(training_df['tweet']))
>>> df.show(5)
+--------------------+--------------+---------+
|               tweet|classification|    dummy|
+--------------------+--------------+---------+
|rt @jiffyclub: wi...|        python|dummyData|
|rt @arnicas: ipyt...|        python|dummyData|
|rt @treycausey: i...|        python|dummyData|
|what's my best op...|        python|dummyData|
|rt @raymondh: #py...|        python|dummyData|
+--------------------+--------------+---------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Comment: Thank you. I've learned that the show() doesn't necessarily cause the full parsing to occur if there isn't a need to for the N specified.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're misdefining the problem, and maybe simplifying your lambda for the purposes of this question but hiding the real problem.

Your stack trace reads

```
File "<ipython-input-12-4bc30395aac5>", line 4, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I run this code it works fine:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

training_df = sqlContext.sql("select 'foo' as tweet, 'bar' as classification")

def dummy_function(data_str):
     cleaned_str = 'dummyData'
     return cleaned_str

dummy_function_udf = udf(dummy_function, StringType())
df = training_df.withColumn("dummy", dummy_function_udf(training_df['tweet']))
df.show()

+-----+--------------+---------+
|tweet|classification|    dummy|
+-----+--------------+---------+
|  foo|           bar|dummyData|
+-----+--------------+---------+
```

Are you sure there isn't some other bug in your `dummy_function_udf`? What is the 'real' udf you are using - apart from this sample version?

Comment: Thanks so much for answering. It looks like text data is always evil and will break your parsers. I expected any errors with parsing to have shown up with training_df.show(5) but it looks like it only parses the first N records if done with no other transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a similar problem. Can I follow up and ask what does "udf" mean here? I copied the code to my shell only to find the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'udf' is not defined`

Comment: User defined function.

Comment: I got this. My original question was solved when I saw this line :  `from pyspark.sql.functions import udf` It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below one works with the spark2,

```
import hashlib
import uuid
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def customencoding(s):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(s.encode('utf-8'))
    d = m.hexdigest()
    return d

spark.udf.register("udf_customhashing32adadf", customencoding, StringType())

spark.sql("SELECT udf_customhashing32adadf('test') as rowid").show(10, False)
```

You can implement it in the same way.