# PySpark: Transform values of given column in the DataFrame

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to PySpark and Spark in general.
I would like to apply transformation on a given column in the DataFrame, essentially call a function for each value on that specific column.

I have my DataFrame `df` that looks like this:

```
df.show()

+------------+--------------------+
|version     |         body       |
+------------+--------------------+
|           1|9gIAAAASAQAEAAAAA...|
|           2|2gIAAAASAQAEAAAAA...|
|           3|3gIAAAASAQAEAAAAA...|
|           1|7gIAKAASAQAEAAAAA...|
+------------+--------------------+
```

I need to read value of `body` column for each row where the `version` is `1` and then decrypt it (I have my own logic/function which takes a string and returns a decrypted string). Finally, write the decrypted values in csv format to a S3 bucket.

```
def decrypt(encrypted_string: str):
    # code that returns decrypted string
```

So, When I do following, I get the corresponding filtered values to which I need to apply my decrypt function.

```
df.where(col('version') =='1')\
     .select(col('body')).show()

+--------------------+
|                body|
+--------------------+
|9gIAAAASAQAEAAAAA...|
|7gIAKAASAQAEAAAAA...|
+--------------------+
```

However, I am not clear how to do that. I tried to use `collect()` but then it defeats the purpose of using Spark.

I also tried using `.rdd.map` as follows but that did not work.

```
df.where(col('version') =='1')\
     .select(col('body'))\
     .rdd.map(lambda x: decrypt).toDF().show()

OR 

     .rdd.map(decrypt).toDF().show()
```

Could someone please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
decrypt_udf = udf(decrypt, StringType())
df.where(col('version') =='1').withColumn('body', decrypt_udf('body'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I tried based on the post I mentioned.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got some clue from this post: [Pyspark DataFrame UDF on Text Column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34803855/948268).
Looks like I can simply get it with following. I was doing it without using `udf` earlier, so it wasn't working.

```
dummy_function_udf = udf(decrypt, StringType())

df.where(col('version') == '1')\
   .select(col('body')) \
   .withColumn('decryptedBody', dummy_function_udf('body')) \
   .show()
```